# I am trying to actively track user coordinates and display a line in js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to copy a feature from autocad like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Av6y.png) which is the line function.
Things I did:

1. Ask for the first coordinate
2. Ask for the second coordinate
3. Display the final line

Things I want to know how to do:

1. After the first click (for the first coordinates), I want to display a line each 50ms where the user is putting his cursor even if he isn't clicking
2. Delete that line every time he changes the cursor position until the user clicks

This is have i have now:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawLine(first, last) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(first.x, first.y);
    ctx.lineTo(last.x, last.y);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    return {x, y};
}

function lFunction(e) {  
    const clicked = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
    itteration++;
    if (itteration % 2 != 0) {
        firstClick = clicked;
    } else if (itteration % 2 == 0) {
        drawLine(firstClick, clicked);
    }
}

lFunction();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If it doesn't work it is because i took it from a bigger file, which I prefer not to share.

Thank you for any help in advance.
I am still a beginner, so please do not be harsh.

P.S: If someone could help me with the degree thing and the auto refreshing length.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to 'remember' your line drawing action, update it as the mouse moves, and every 50ms clear the canvas and redraw the most recent line.

```
var currentLine = {
  start: null,
  finish: null
}

var currentlyDrawing = false;

var mouseTracker = function(e){
  currentLine.finish = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(!currentlyDrawing) {
    let position = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
    currentLine.start = position;
    currentLine.finish = position;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseTracker);
    currentlyDrawing = true;
  } else {
    currentlyDrawing = false;
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseTracker);
  }
})

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawLine(currentLine.start, currentLine.finish);
}, 50);
```

Now, obviously this only works for a single line.

The next step is replace `currentLine` with an array of `line`. Then your click event handler will create a new `line` (if it is not `currentlyDrawing`) and append it to the list of `line`, and `mouseTracker` will set the `finish` property on the last `line` in the array. Then your timer function will clear the screen, then iterate through the `line` array and call `drawLine` on each of them.